# Reduce Transparency In Mac through Terminal

Tags: objective-c, macos, terminal, system

I'm trying to make an app that will disable/reduce transparency in Mac OSX like in the system preferences accessibility tab, using terminal. I want to use the `system()` command. I've found this command:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleEnableMenuBarTransparency -bool false`

But unfortunately this is only for the menu bar and not for the entire system, can someone tell me a command to disable/reduce all transparency throughout all of OSX? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it for a user with this:

```
defaults write com.apple.universalaccess reduceTransparency 1
```

I couldn't find a way to set it system-wide.